# Need to Display Buttons in Magento Frontend

Tags: magento

I am new to Magento enterprise edition. I need to enable some buttons(Page, News & Video) regarding the product details in my front-end. On mouse click, i need to fetch data related to the product from another website through search key. Is there any solution through which we can directly fetch the data on mouse click or is there any third party tool through which we can access data

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement an my understanding you need some data to be fetched from another site on mouse click for a product.

On mouse click event you need to do an **Ajax** request passing the product id or something that is being identified and used by other site as a parameter